# How to change folder structure of dist in angular-cli build?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After building my angular app using --prod parameter angular-cli generates approx. 24 files. I want a structure that is much cleaner (only folders and the index.html). For example I want all generated files moved to a folder called "core".

The structure of my dist folder is that:

```
 dist/
 dist/assets
 dist/config
 dist/... 23 files ...
 index.html
```

I would like to have this structure (automatically generated):

```
dist/
dist/assets
dist/config
dist/core/... 23 files ...
index.html
```

I'm using @angular/cli version 1.4.7.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: why would you care so much about dist folder?

Comment: Because at the moment if administrators download the app and update their old installation they have to delete 23 files, the assets folder and the index.html file and copy the new 23 files, the new index.html and assets folder to their installation path (overwrite does not delete the old files).
With other words it is more comfortable for users to just replace 2 folders and one file instead of 24 files and one folder.

Comment: I am also looking to customize build structure as it needs to specify which files fallen to which folder
I want to make to precise

Comment: @Satish did you found a solutions?

Comment: @Satish I found a way to change the folder structure. See the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I created a bash script that allows to change the folder structure after building with ng prod. You can find it here:
https://gist.github.com/julianpoemp/41aad8d1d2fb888d422563cfbd76b8f0

According to a angular/cli developer this is currently not possible. But if you also want this feature, please upvote the issue on github:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14014

If there are a lot of people looking for this option to set the folder structure of dist, the developers think about adding it.

Comment: You could even achieve this without bash script just by modifying the `angular.json` build configuration. Checkout my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60299668/angular-9-build-bundle-directory/60375578?noredirect=1#comment106846442_60375578