# how to change the path of Angular app scripts on production build?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

How to put all my main Angular scripts and css file such as:

main.[hash].js, scripts.[hash].js, styles.[hash].css, runtime.[hash].js, polyfills.[hash].js

in another folder (like shows in below image) automatically on every build project. I want only two folder in my dist folder first-one is assets folder and second is ng-main that holds the app scrips and css and last-one is index.html file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this isn't a thing in angular and angular don't see any benefit to making it possible either. See [This issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14014)

There are work around solutions i.e. creating a script to run post build.
See [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984456/how-to-change-folder-structure-of-dist-in-angular-cli-build) for a possible solution.

Alternatively.....You could also just add it to your npm scripts:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "build": "ng build && bash mkdir dist/App/ng-main && bash find dist/App -type f ! \( -iname '*.html' \) -exec `echo mv {} ./dist/App/ng-main/` \;",
  ...
}
```

then run

```
npm run build
```